# Cropping osm.pbf data without missing overlapping features?

Tags: openstreetmap, command-line, clip

for our offline maps tool we use *.osm.pbf data for input. As we often need cross border selections or just a country with some "buffer" around borders we use cropped osm data using osmctools.

Example:

```
osmconvert europe-latest.osm.pbf -B=CH_border_buffer10km_v2.poly --complete-ways -o=Switzerland_custom_buffer.osm.pbf
```

However the resulting map has some features missing:

[image: Switzerland_offline]

most apparent is the missing Bodensee - compared with online OSM layer provided by Terrestris:

[image: Switzerland_online_Terrestris_OSM]

Can I somehow solve this so the cropped data does not remove all features overlapping the trimline?

The resulting format however has to be osm.pbf.
I found a mention of "--complete-multipolygons" parameter [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert), but osmctools (0.6-1 from ubuntu repository) does not offer me this.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for --complete-ways which is more suitable than multipolygons. If you have 32 bit windows and input bigger than 2gb than there will be problem.

```
This option, and that described in the next two sections, 
will limit the size of the input file to 2 GiB if your 
operating system is 32 bit Windows.
```

Comment: I am already using this option. Input is about 20 GB and OS is 64bit linux.